# Configuring sqlalchemy for windows

Tags: python, sql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

Is there any tutorials about how to set-up sqlalchemy for windows? I went to www.sqlalchemy.org and they don't have clear instructions about set-up for windows. When I opened the zipped package, I see distribute_setup, ez_setup and setup.py among other files but it doesn't see to install sqlalchemy.

Comment: Get `pip` and install it via `pip install sqlalchemy`.

Comment: http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/python-development-windows/

Comment: @Cooper: I am not looking for installing python, just a good tool for installing sqlalchemy without any hassle.

Comment: @Blender: Can you little more elaborate how does pip work for windows. pip install sqlalchemy looked like the bash command to me for linux terminal.

Comment: No, after you install `pip` it lets you install Python packages easily. Also, read that link that @JCooper pointed to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After unzipping open a command prompt and cd into the unzipped directory then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Here is a link to the installation guilde:

[Sql Alchemy Instalation Guide](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/intro.html#installation)

Answer (score 1):

The Command `pip install sqlalchemy` will download the necessary files and run `setup.py install` for you.